# How to write Quran via Latex?

Tags: input-encodings

I get this message when I compile it "
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ٰ (U+0670)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX. "

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}
\usepackage{quran}
\begin{document}
\quransurah[94]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `quran` package is for preparing files compiled with `xelatex` (or, as Davislor notes, `lualatex`).  That is, it uses `latex` macros with the `xetex` (or `luatex`) binary, which handles unicode natively.  By contrast, `arabtex` uses `latex` macros with the `pdftex` binary, which works with older and more limited encodings.  That’s why `arabtex` requires you to specify `fontenc` and `inputenc` — both things you should never do when using `xetex` or `luatex`.

Here’s a small example of the usage of `quran`.  But be sure to read its manual, because it offers many options and commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{quran,polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\setmainfont{Amiri}
\usepackage{bidi}
\begin{document}
\setRTL
\textarabic{\quransurah}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Note that there is an Amiri Quran font.

Comment: It is also possible to load `babel` and the `\babelprovide[import, main]{arabic}` along with `fontspec`.

Comment: @Davislor The `babel` approach isn’ working for me: the letters appear in the right order, but disconnected.

Comment: Load `\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}` in LuaLaTeX. You might need `bidi=default` in XeLaTeX.

Comment: Maybe I should do a separate answer. This is getting to the point where it doesn't belong in comments.

Comment: @Davislor The `quran` documentation includes an example with `luatex`.  I hadn’t thought of looking for one and tried `babel` only with `xetex`, because that `quran` documentation is in the `doc/xelatex` directory, which seems odd for a package that’s not xetex-only.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example using the `babel` package and the Amiri Quran font on LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{quran}

\babelprovide[import, main]{arabic}

\babelfont{rm}%
          [Ligatures=Common]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont{sf}%
          [Ligatures=Common]{Libertinus Sans}
\babelfont{tt}%
          {Libertinus Mono}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}%
          [BoldFont = {Amiri Bold},
           ItalicFont = {Amiri Slanted},
           BoldItalicFont = {Amiri Bold Slanted},
           Renderer=HarfBuzz]
          {Amiri Quran}

\begin{document}
\quransurah[94]
\end{document}
```

On XeLaTeX, you would need to change the option to `\usepackage[bidi=default]{babel}`.

In case you need to use more than one language, it sets up the Libertinus font family, an extension by the designer of Amiri of Linux Libertine, as the default font family.  This is an excellent companion font.

Comment: Do you get connected script with `xetex` and `\usepackage[bidi=default]{babel}`? I don’t, with an up-to-date TeX Live 2019.

Comment: @Thérèse Yes, if I also remove the `Contextuals=` feature.

Answer (score 1):

The following example shows a possible and simultaneous usage of quran and quran-ur packages with English translation (without using arabtex or arabxetex or babel or fontspec). Required fonts  can also be downloaded from
https://fonts.qurancomplex.gov.sa/wp02/?s=KFGQPC+Uthmanic+Script+HAFS , and https://urdufonts.net/fonts/jameel-noori-nastaleeq-regular as a .ttf file and hence can be installed. Use XeLaTeX compiler.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{quran}
\usepackage{quran-ur}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
 %IMPORTANT. Allows using multiple languages in document.
\setmainlanguage[numerals=eastern]{urdu}  
 % use numerals=eastern or western if urdu numbers are desired
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5,WordSpace=5]{Jameel Noori Nastaleeq.ttf} 
 % or another
\newfontfamily\naskh[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5,WordSpace=1]{UthmanicHafs1 Ver18.ttf}
 %MUHAMMADI QURANIC FONT.ttf or UthmanicHafs1 Ver18.ttf or  Arial or Amiri or Scheherazade
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin,Scale=1.3]{Times New Roman}  % or XITS
\begin{document}
\setstretch{1.5}
{\naskh
     \quranayah[An-Nisa][32]
    
}
    \begin{center}
        
        {\large
            \texturdu{\quranayahur[An-Nisa][32]}\\
            
        }
    \end{center}

\textenglish{
    
\noindent   Do not desire those things (religious or worldly virtues and status over which you have no control) with which Allah Ta’ala has favoured some of you over others (so as to not create jealousy and hatred between yourselves)   
}
\end{document}
```